# Unable to work out innerHTML setup

Tags: javascript, html

I am a bit new to Javascript, but I am trying to setup a very simple user input/response system. For some reason, I have run into this before where innerHTML was not displaying information given to it. Here is the basic setup of what I am trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>titles are lame</title>
    <link/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper"><div id="text">Test</div>
<br>
<input type='text' id="input"><input type="submit"id="submit" onclick="act()">
<input type="button" value="Button" onclick="act()">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That was the HTML just in case I was missing something simple. Here is the Javascript.

```
var state = 0;
var inputf = getElementById("input");
var text = getElementById('text');
var input, name, age;

function act(){
input = inputf.content;
switch(state){
    case 0:
        text.innerHTML = "This is supposed to overwrite Test text.";
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling doing `var text = getElementById('text');` in the global scope of your script, which means it will happen as soon as the script is loaded, possibly before the rest of the page is loaded. Thus, the element you are trying to get might not yet exist.

Try moving the initialization of these variables inside of `act()`.

Comment: Sweet, got it. I keep forgetting that Javascript loads before the rest of the page does. Because I needed those variables to be global instead of just inside the function (so they could be accessed from the function regardless of when it was called) I defined them in a script at the very bottom of <body>. That did the trick.